# Insert Key value pair into existing JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json

I have a json like below

```
{
    "name": "Ram",
    "Age": "25",
    "ContactDetails": {
        "MobNo": "1"
    }
}
```

Please suggest how to add

```
"Address": {
    "No": "123",
    "Street": "abc"
}
```

into ContactDetails

Comment: Deserialize the JSON string to an object, add the address details and serialize the object.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to and post some sample code if you're stuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work (using Newtonsoft.Json)

```
var json = 
    @"{
        ""name"": ""Ram"",
        ""Age"": ""25"",
        ""ContactDetails"": {
            ""MobNo"": ""1""
        }
    }";

var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
jObject["ContactDetails"]["Address"] = JObject.Parse(@"{""No"":""123"",""Street"":""abc""}");

var resultAsJsonString = jObject.ToString();
```

The result is:

```
{
  "name": "Ram",
  "Age": "25",
  "ContactDetails": {
    "MobNo": "1",
    "Address": {
      "No": "123",
      "Street": "abc"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: one more query ,i need to insert some more values into existing jsonarray   {"products":["a","b,"c","etc"]}  , please suggest how to do it

Comment: Just use JArray: `var jObject = JObject.Parse(json); var jArray = jObject["products"] as JArray; jArray.Add("new_product");`

Answer (score 1):

One of the options would be use Newtonsoft's Json.NET to parse json into [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm), find needed token, and add property to it:

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var jObjToExtend = (JObject)jObj.SelectToken("$.ContactDetails");
jObjToExtend.Add("Address", JObject.FromObject(new { No = "123", Street = "abc" }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Deserialize the JSON into object, then insert the value that you need to insert to it.
Then, Serialize the object into JSON.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to