# insert data into existing JSON Array in C#

Tags: c#, json

I need to add some more data into existing JSON

eg:

```
{
    "OrderId":"abc",
    "products":["a","b","c","etc"]
}
```

how to add more into products

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON Array. JSON is a text format, like CSV or XML.

Comment: As such, how do you have this JSON right now? As a string? As an object?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Your linked answer is about javascript, not c#. Also, despite being text format json has concept of array elements.

Comment: @GuruStron JSON has a format for serializing arrays, but it does not have arrays.

Comment: The proper duplicate is [json add new object to existing json file C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33081102/215552)

Comment: @HereticMonkey 1) this is also not a proper duplicate 2) if you don't agree with wording you can dicuss it with [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) or [ietf rfc](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt) having next wording: "This is a JSON array containing two objects:"

Comment: @GuruStron "this is also not a proper duplicate" is not swaying me with well-reasoned arguments. If you don't feel it answers the question, edit the question to make it clear why it is not (as described in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)). W3Schools is not what I would consider a trustworthy source of anything. I may bring it up with the IETF.

Comment: @HereticMonkey it does not answer the question because it is about adding an object to existing json (which OP knows how to do, see link in my answer) and not a new element to an array in existing json, and there is a difference in handling those in c#, not a big one though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach would be similar to used in answer to your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62170221/2501279) question, but you will need to convert element to `JArray`:

```
var x = @"{
    'OrderId':'abc',
    'products':['a','b','c','etc']
}";

var jObj = JObject.Parse(x);
((JArray)jObj["products"]).Add("new");
```

Comment: @RoadsideRomeozz was glad to help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json); 
var jArray = jObject["products"] as JArray; 
jArray?.Add("new_product");
```